# Accessibility : Prevent browser from overriding CSS in input fields

Tags: css, firefox, dojo, accessibility

Browsers have their accessibility options. For eg. I can use firefox to set background color as black, and text color as yellow for high accessibility. When this is done some areas of website don't function properly. In my case all input fields have their background and text color both as black.

I can detect whether browser is overriding my colors. But I don't seem to have control on how to correct those. If I write new CSS rule, it always gets ignored.

I'm using DOJO, and I have correct aria defined for my input text boxes.

I have tried using background-image for the textbox div, tried the color property to change the color

To get an idea of what I mean you can run an example of text box from dojo website in high contrast from here -

Firefox --> Preferences --> Colors --> Background black --> text color yellow --> Always override

Open this example and run -

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/TextBox.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So firstly I don't think you need to worry about overriding a user browser preferences. But as a quick answer have you tried the "appearance" CSS property? That might work.

More specifically the -moz-appearance property.

```
-moz-appearance: none;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

If that works you can proceed to style it to make it look the way you want it to look.

Comment: Thanks Craig! -moz-appearance: none; didn't have any effect. But -moz-apperance say "listbox" works fine for my combo-boxes and "radio" corrects appearance of my radio buttons. This is great help.

Comment: Oh great! Glad I could help :).